# SQL Server : TOP 10 query by occurrence without using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m trying to write a query of the `Top 10` occurrences of a column in my database. But I don´t want to see it in a group by mode.

I have a database with 40000 rows and with 20 columns, and I want to write a query that returns x rows with the top 10 occurrences in one specific column.

When I use this:

```
Select top 10 colum.name
from table.name
```

what I get is the top 10 rows in the database.

When I use this:

```
select top 10 colum.name
From table.name
group by colum.name
order by colum.name DESC
```

I get my top 10 occurrences but group by my column, and what I want is to see that same top 10 but with all the rows displayed.

I don´t know if this is a dumb question, but I'm losing all my cool with this one!

So thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add desired output?

Comment: For one column value there can be many rows. What rows do you want to show in that case?

Comment: Being nitpicky: it's a **column** (with "m"-"n") - not a "colum"... (you have that consistently spelled incorrectly in your post)

Comment: Thank you marc_s, it works like magic. Sorry for my English, I'm Portuguese, and I don´t use English as often as i like to. Thank you to bendaclear. Your ideia work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
;WITH Top10Distinct AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 YourColumn
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    ORDER BY YourColumn DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable tbl
INNER JOIN Top10Distinct cte ON tbl.YourColumn = cte.YourColumn
```

The CTE first fetches the `TOP 10 DISTINCT` values for `YourColumn` and then you join those top 10 values against the actual "base" table `dbo.YourTable`, thus retrieving **all rows** in full from the base table that have one of the top 10 distinct column values.

Answer (score 0):

```
you could use row_number()/rank()/dense_rank () depending on the requirement
```

ex :

```
with cte as
(
select name,ROW_NUMBER() over (id order by id) as rn
);

select * from cte where rn <=10
```

this outputs you 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dirty sub-query:

```
Select column.name
from table.name
Where column.name IN (Select top 10 column.name
                      from table.name
                      group by column.name
                      order by count(*) desc)
```